# How do I download txt web content using perl

Tags: php, perl

I am trying to download data from this [data page](https://www.ogimet.com/synopsc.phtml.en). I have tried a number of scripts I googled. On the data page I have to select the countries I want, one at a time. The one script  which gets close to what I want is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;

my $url = 'https://www.ogimet.com/ultimos_synops2.php?lang=en&estado=Zamb&fmt=txt&Send=Send';
my $file = 'Zamb.txt';
getstore($url, $file);
```

However this script gives me the page, not the data. I would appreciate if I can get help to download the data, if this is possible.
I would also appreciate to do it in php if this may be an easier alternative.

Comment: And what is "the data" for you?

Comment: On the page, there is a selection of country and time of the data required. Once these are selected, there is a send button which opens a data page. The data is in ascii (text) format. I hope this clarifies the issue.

Comment: If the response content already is the data, where's the problem?

Comment: Perhaps I did not provide more precision. On the page, apart from selecting the country and time, I only want only the latest (or specific time) synop and metar messages, amongst several message types available. What am getting right now is a document in html format without the data.

Comment: `GET -o text 'https://www.ogimet.com/ultimos_synops2.php?lang=en&estado=Spa&fmt=txt&Send=Send'` or postprocess to strip everything not between `<pre>` / `</pre>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link returns text wrapped in HTML. Simplest approach would be to use HTML::FormatText and HTML::Parse to get the text only version.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TreeBuilder;
use HTML::FormatText;


my $url = 'https://www.ogimet.com/ultimos_synops2.php?lang=en&estado=Zamb&fmt=txt&Send=Send';
my $text = HTML::FormatText->new(leftmargin=>0, rightmargin=>100000000000)->format(HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_url($url));

my $file = 'Zamb.txt';
open (my $fh, '>', $file);
print $fh $text;
close ($fh);
```

- [`HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_url($url)`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder#new_from_url) - download and parse the html
- [`HTML::FormatText`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::FormatText)`->new(leftmargin=>0, rightmargin=>100000000000)` - intialize the html format - set the right margin to a big value to prevent wrapping

This is the content of Zamb.txt afterwards.

```
 $ cat Zamb.txt
##########################################################
# Query made at 02/29/2020 18:15:54 UTC
##########################################################

##########################################################
# latest SYNOP reports from Zambia before 02/29/2020 18:15:54 UTC
##########################################################
202002291200 AAXX 29124 67855 42775 51401 10310 20168 3//// 48/// 85201
                   333 5//// 85850 83080=
```

My php fu isn't up to date, but for PHP, I think you can use the following:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.ogimet.com/ultimos_synops2.php?lang=en&estado=Zamb&fmt=txt&Send=Send';
$content = strip_tags(file_get_contents($url));
echo substr($content, strpos($content, '###############'));
```

Note: I seem to recall that there are some configuration options that might disable fetching URL via file_get_contents so YMMV.

However, the same page there is a note:

> NOTE: If you want to get simply files with synop reports in CSV format without HTML tags consider to use the binary getsynop

This would get you the same data in a easy to use format:

```
$ wget "https://www.ogimet.com/cgi-bin/getsynop?begin=$(date +%Y%m%d0000)&state=Zambia" -o /dev/null -O - | tail -1
67855,2020,02,29,12,00,AAXX 29124 67855 42775 51401 10310 20168 3//// 48/// 85201 333 5//// 85850 83080=
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Sorin. This solves my problem completely in perl. The php code gives an error on my ubuntu. However am very thankful for your time and effort. Just for curiosity, I can write a script to download with wget as you point out. What is the output file name? and what is being sent to /dev/null?

Comment: @ZiloreMumba what error do you get ? `-O -` sends the output to standard in, so you can then go trough tail -1 to get the last line. `-o /dev/null` send the wget log to dev null

Comment: the script you have given above does the job ok. I was just wondering how I would use the wget command you have suggested. In a perl script it gives error of "String found where operator expected at Synops_ogm0.pl line 15, near "wget "https://www.ogimet.com/cgi-bin/getsynop?begin=$(date +%Y%m%d0000)&state=Zambia""
 (Do you need to predeclare wget?)". On the terminal (i.e. outside the script) it gives a long file name with part of the url in the name and no meaningful content.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html - it's a external command - in a perl script you can use LWP to fetch the same url, but you will need also to split it and get just the last line.